# Call an action by Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, httprequest

I work on a `asp.net` mvc project and I want to refresh a drop down by select option of another drop down. For this use ajax but when run request go to error method and not run success method.

**My Script**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

function FillSubject() {

    var GroupServicesId = $('#GroupServices_ID').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Advertisements/FillSubject",
        type: "GET",
        data: { 'GroupServiceID': GroupServicesId },
        dataType:"json",
        success: function (Subjects) {
            $("#Subject_ID").html("");
            $.each(Subjects, function (i, subject) {
                $("#Subject_ID").append($('<option></option>').val(subject.ID).html(subject.strSubjectName));
            });
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert(this.url);
        }
    });
}
</script>`
```

**My Action in Controller**

```
    public JsonResult FillSubject(string GroupServiceID)
    {
        //string GSID = GroupServiceID.Substring(1, (GroupServiceID.Length)-2);
        var Subjects = db.Subjects.Where(c => c.GroupServicesID.ToString() == GroupServiceID);
        var SubjectList = Subjects.Select(sl => new SubjectList { ID = sl.ID, GroupServiceID = sl.GroupServicesID, strSubjectName = sl.strSubjectName });
        return Json(SubjectList,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**And This is my Dropdowns in .cshtml/razor code**

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GroupServices_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GroupServices_ID, new SelectList(GroupServicesList, "ID", "strGroupServiceName"), new { @class = "selectpicker", @onchange = "FillSubject()" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GroupServices_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subject_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Subject_ID, new SelectList(SubjectsList, "ID", "strSubjectName"), new { @class = "selectpicker" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subject_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

update 1 - 22/06/2016

I Change my controller and give `Json result` in `ajax` but don't update my second Dropdown
My result
`[Object { ID="ffb1d85a-a822-41e1-8859-24db2b5bc72e",  GroupServiceID="0cc2cdf6-b9d3-4274-9cc1-31daf5814458",  strSubjectName="برنامه نویسی"}, Object { ID="1f65f038-0111-479a-bdf3-d43eb772af9d",  GroupServiceID="0cc2cdf6-b9d3-4274-9cc1-31daf5814458",  strSubjectName="آموزش زبان خارجه"}]`

Comment: could you please attach debugger at server end and see what error you in your .Net code?

Comment: Also check browser console for any client side error like 404 or 500.

Comment: not call my action for debug and go to ajax error

Comment: ok, so please check browser console. You must be getting 404 bad request. In this case see which complete URL is getting form like `http://yourdomain.com/Advertisements/FillSubject`. Make sure that such URL is valid.

Comment: Did you decorate your `JsonResult` with `HttpGet`?

Comment: @vijayP I get a empty json with this link http://localhost:12473/Advertisements/FillSubject but by send GroupServicesID I get a json and don't get http error

Comment: @GuruprasadRao How do decorate?

Comment: Above the line `public JsonResult FillSubject(string GroupServiceID)` we add `[HttpGet]` thats it..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I do but don't run success method and run error method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give this a try, i'm not Totally sure it will works or not..!! 
**But let's try..**

Change `type: "GET",` to `type: "POST",` in your AJAX request,

`public JsonResult FillSubject(string GroupServiceID)` to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FillSubject(string GroupServiceID)
{
   // do stuff
   return Json(SubjectList,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

  //Updated Code
   return Json(SubjectList);
}
```

> Update

**First of all, try by using simple code like this.**

```
public ActionResult FillSubject(string GroupServiceID)
{
   return Json(true);
}
```

And check the by putting debugger in success method like this,

```
function FillSubject() {

var GroupServicesId = $('#GroupServices_ID').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "/Advertisements/FillSubject?GroupServiceID=" + "test",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (result) {
        debugger;
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert(this.url);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Now try by remove the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` from the Action, See the updated answer

Comment: @ Smit Patel this change don't change my result . action don't call :(

Comment: Something is going wrong in your action, First you need to remove all 'do stuff' from Your action. and try with this Existing code that you posted in your question. Just remove the Stuff from Action, `TRY THIS BY SIMPLE CODE`

Comment: I change my action by return GroupServiceID but Run error method in ajax

Comment: I try by your update but run error function and don't run success method

Comment: I add debugger in error function and get e.responseText. I see undefined in alert

Comment: Try using this updated Jquery code, Success will hit or not??

Comment: I get my result in ajax but don't update second dropdown